# SharePoint WebPart Solutions and Application Server

Tags: 2013, project-server

Upon trying to deploy webpart wsp solutions from App server, the feature xml file never gets added to the 15 hive on the application server, the feature does get added to the 15 hive on the web front end server, it is almost like the feature components are never propagated to App Server, which is where trying to enable feature fails as it cannot find the feature xml.

Commands being run in the exact order:

```
Add-SPsolution -LiteralPath "c:\..."

Install-SPSolution -Identity "solutionname.wsp" -GACDeployment -FullTrustBinDeployment -WebApplication "http://consoto.com/" 

Install-SPFeature "FeatureName" -Force (Fails with the error "Could not find feature.xml at ..\15\Templates\Features")

Enable-SPFeature -Identity "FeatureName" -Url "http://contoso.com/pwa" -Force  (Fails with the error "Could not find feature.xml at ..\15\Templates\Features")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature likely has a dependency on the Foundation Web service being in a Started state. Start the Foundation Web on your Application server and it should populate the feature XML to the 15 hive.

Comment: All the feature has is a visual web part, this technet article [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199.aspx) here suggests that the service be turned off on non-web front end servers? Is turning this service on a recommended approach?

Comment: TN has some bad info. Yes, you should enable Foundation Web on all servers.

Comment: Thanks, I will try enabling the service and deploy the solution, btw, I found this on another technet article --> "This service provides web server functionality. It is started by default on web servers. Custom features scoped to web applications may not display in Central Administration as intended if this service is not started on the server running Central Administration and if the feature cannot be deployed globally." In a way contradicting the previous article.

Comment: Starting the Foundation Web service did the trick, thanks much!

Comment: All the activated features now don't show up under site features list, did an IISReset to be sure too, is there something else I am missing? The features did install, I can add the web parts to the page.

Comment: If they're hidden features, they won't show up there (or you're looking at the wrong scope for the features). You can do a `Get-SPFeature` to validate that it is there.

Comment: The features are not hidden, but as they are not deployed globally and scoped to site, they won't probably show up in the list of site features, I believe?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue immediately,I would do this

- copy the feature.xml file from web front server and place in the correct directory at App Server
- Now Reset IIS
- Restart the SharePoint Timer service.

Comment: This would beat the whole purpose of automating deployments.

Comment: you are right, thats why i said immediate fix otherwise start the foundation web servics.

Comment: Starting Foundation Web is an immediate fix with zero downtime for the Application server services.